# Silverstripe 3.0 customize tools panel

Tags: content-management-system, panel, silverstripe

I want to show some customized content in the left panel which usually contains the treeview.

As the stuff in this panel will be an editable Gridfield wich should be related to the EditForm, I tried to built a new EditFormTools panel in this way:

1. I copied the CMSMain_Content.ss in mysite/templates/Includes and changed $Tools into $EditFormTools
2. I created the file CMSMain_EditFormTools.ss in the same directory with this code:

   ```
   <div class="cms-content-tools west cms-panel" data-expandOnClick="true" data-layout-type="border" id="cms-content-tools-CMSMain">
      <div class="cms-panel-content west">
        <% include Test %>
      </div>
   </div>
   ```
3. I created a Test.php with:

   ```
   class Test extends CMSMain{

      public $var = 'test';

      public  function testfunction(){
         $variable = 'hakuna matata';
         return $variable;
      }

   }
   ```
4. Then I created a Test.ss with this code:

   ```
   some Text
   $var
   $testfunction
   $variable
   ```

The Panel appears in my CMS now but it only contains "some Text". So the include of Test.ss works perfectly fine but passing variables from Test.php to Test.ss doesn't.

Can anybody help?

Greetings

Comment: $testfunction won't be in scope after you call $EditFormTools. EditFormTools is where your testfunction should be.

Answer (score 0):

It may not directly answer your question but may give you direction. 
You need to extend a controller class. 
Then you can use a called functions to tell controller which template file it should use using renderWith().
for example,

```
  public function index(){
     return $this->renderWith("Test");
 }
```

Then your function references in Test.ss will call functions in Test.php given it is the controller. 
If Test class is not the controller rendering the template, the template doesnt know where your variable returning function is. 
By the way, you can pass variables from layout to include template.